# Scenes remember using AI, CNN and RNN

Tags: conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

Consider the following scenario ( image ). I wanna develop AI, to understand a particular event and sequence or the chain of it.

Scene  1 :- First the ball is passed to Player 1. Then Player 1 could CATCH the ball OR MISS the ball.

Scene 2 :- Player 1 passes the ball to Player 2. Then Player 2 could CATCH the ball OR MISS the ball.

There are more other combinations, but lets limit to 2 scenes. What my AI wants to do is, to keep remember this two scenes and the chain ! What happened in each scene.

So What I expect to know from you is, How could I implement this kind of AI, What kind of methodologies and technologies I should apply to develop this AI. as far as I learn I found RNN, CNN can do this, dunno exactly they are. And what kind of drawbacks/challenges you see in this reach. And general steps should take to approach this.

Thank you.

[image: See the Image]

Answer (score 0):

Google and others have been using Deep Q, a.k.a a combination of deep neural networks and reinforcement learning to train AI agents to play games. This is, I guess, what you are trying to do.

Several tutorials, examples and research articles discuss the subject. Start with these:

- **Reddit discussion**: [I trained a deep Q network built in tensorflow to play Atari pong](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/3y16pa/i_trained_a_deep_q_network_built_in_tensorflow_to/).
- **Medium article**: [Simple Reinforcement Learning with Tensorflow Part 4: Deep Q-Networks and Beyond](https://medium.com/@awjuliani/simple-reinforcement-learning-with-tensorflow-part-4-deep-q-networks-and-beyond-8438a3e2b8df)

Then check this **research article**: [Playing Atari with Deep Reinforcement Learning](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~vmnih/docs/dqn.pdf)